# Android strange behavior on https response

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gson, android-volley

I've lost my sunday trying to understand what is going wrong with my https calls. This is my code to make a call to a https rest service:

```
String url = AppUtils.env.getValue()+"announcementsservice/getYears";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String jsonResponse) {

            AnnouncementsResponse response = (AnnouncementsResponse)
                        AppUtils.convertJsonResponse(AnnouncementsResponse.class, jsonResponse);

            arrayAdapter.clear();
            arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
            for (Integer year : response.getYears()) {
                arrayAdapter.add(String.valueOf(year));
            }
            arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            VolleyLog.d("tag", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while loading ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

I'm using volley to call the service and gson to parse the response. I've tried the code on a nexus 4 simulator and all is working fine. Then I tried to install the app on a Vernee physical device (os 5.1 sdk 22) via usb and all is working fine. Then I tried to install the app via google play store (alpha testing) on the same Vernee device and the code throws a null pointer exception. I tried everything to understand the problem but the only thing I understood is that the response is arriving, but there is an error converting it with gson:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method     'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

This is the response (same on simulator and physical device):

```
{
  "result": 1,
  "announcementsList": null,
  "years": [2018]
}
```

I'm becoming crazy!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons which may cause such problem is Proguard !
When you debug an app, the model are as the same as you see. So Gson model is the same as server response and everything works fine. But when you build the Apk it become obfuscated. so the class names and parameters change. that why when you want to parse it with GSON it can't understand and the result of that is null.

what you should do is to tell the progurad to prevent changing your models which you used in GSON serializing. add this line to your proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.test.app.models.** { *; }
```

Instead of `com.test.app.models` enter the package name of the repository where all your models in it

Comment: awesome. the problem was pro guard. Thanks a lot for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Only possible problem I can think of is your pro guard is truncating variable name.

So put  `@SerializedName("years")@Expose`  above your variable `years`

Comment: Your solution was good too, but i can check only one answer as valid :(
Thanks!

Comment: @Giamma You are welcome and you can always upvote more than answer ;-p